# How to plot pandas pivot with different scales?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

my dataframe of pivot is looking like this.

```
 df=
                   DATA
Type            P_A       P_B
Time        
11:38:56    500706.0    981098.0
11:39:46    501704.0    984751.0
11:40:26    501704.0    984737.0
11:43:18    502758.0    987173.0
```

I want to plot this dataframe. `df.plot()` is works but since values are very much different on scale so ploting needs to be on different axis . How to do that?

Comment: which plot you want ? bar, histogram etc ?

Comment: i want line chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) has an option `secondary_y`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['11:38:56', '11:39:46', '11:40:26', '11:43:18'],
                   'P_A': [500706., 501704., 501704., 502758.],
                   'P_B': [981098., 984751., 984737., 987173.]})
df.plot(x='Time', y=['P_A','P_B'], secondary_y=['P_B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [secondary axis-argument to pandas plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51784495/plot-dataframe-with-two-y-axes).

```
df['P_A'].plot()
df['P_B'].plot(secondary_y=True)
```