# How to create a double axis for one graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I'm trying to have two y-axes with the same x-axis.

This is what I have tried. But the suicide rates are not showing up on the graph.
I'm new to this, so I was wondering if anyone could spot why its not showing.
[The picture is supposed to look like this with suicide rates in red and trust in blue with country as the x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNHLH.png)

```py
def suicidevstrustcountryplot(dat):
    
    # Does income index change trust for female led countries?
    # dat.plot(x ='Country', y='Income', kind = 'line')
    # plt.show()
    # create figure and axis objects with subplots()
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    # make a plot
    ax.plot(dat.Country, dat.Trust, color="red", marker="o")
    # set x-axis label
    ax.set_xlabel("Country",fontsize=14)
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
      label.set_rotation(90)
      label.set_ha('right')
    # set y-axis label
    ax.set_ylabel("Trust",color="red",fontsize=14)
    # twin object for two different y-axis on the sample plot
    ax2=ax.twinx()
    # make a plot with different y-axis using second axis object
    ax2.plot(dat.Country, dat.Trust,color="blue",marker="o")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Suicide rate",color="blue",fontsize=14)
    plt.show()
    # save the plot as a file
    fig.savefig('two_different_y_axis_for_single_python_plot_with_twinx.jpg',
                format='jpeg',
                dpi=100,
                bbox_inches='tight')
suicidevstrustcountryplot(Femaletrust)
suicidevstrustcountryplot.suicidevstrustcountryplot.sort_values(ascending=False)[:10].plot(kind='scatter' ,title='Country')
```

Comment: You can use either twinx or secondary_y like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46063451/6361531

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are seeing you use your code?

Comment: This code should work. What I see is that your y data is the same for both plots (dat.Trust), which results in overlapping lines.