# Creating Python Chart withThree Axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, figure

Suppose I have the following data for five different categories:
[image]

I would like to create a figure showing the mean (and the 1-std.-band around the return) in something like the graph below (mean and std in y-axis, the different categories x-axis). Would it also be possible to add the Sharpe as a red/orange triangle in the same graph (with a secondary y-axis on right)?

[image]

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46063451/6361531

Comment: Which plot do I choose to get the result that I have described (including the triangles for the Sharpe)? Is there a name for this?

Comment: You would just need to overlay a scatterplot on top of the graph that you posted above. So first `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, afterwards your code to generate the plot above, making sure to set `ax=ax` and lastly `plt.scatter(...,ax=ax)`